# Prove linear independent vectors are A-conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given vectors $u_0, u_1, ..., u_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent and a positive definite matrix $A$. It seems to me that $u_iAu_j=0 \; if \; i \neq j$, is that true? Could someone help explain why it is true or if it false why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false. A counterexample: $A$ is the identity $I_{2\times 2}$, $u_0 = (1,0)$ and $u_1 = (1, 1)$.